# Apalike2: how to cite multiple authors instead of one author et al

Tags: natbib, apa-style

Apalike2 always only cites one author and than "et al".

But i want to show all the authors the first time I reference to it. How to do this?
I need something like citep which shows all authors.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

\makeindex 
\begin{document}

...text
\citep{Name} => OnePerson et al. instead of all names

\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: That's what `apalike2` does. If you're required to use it, then stick with its specs.

Comment: Well i need something like apalike2 but with that possibility any ideas?

Comment: Not enough expert in bad bibliography styles, sorry. `;-)`

Comment: Hmm, ok and isn't there an extension or something i can add to have this feature. Just started with Latex so i also don't know much about it ^^

Comment: Have you tried loading `natbib` with the option `longnamesfirst`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything :/ (\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib} ?)